# Setting environment variable in python for google bigquery in Mac

Tags: python-3.x

Before calling the Jupyter Notebook, i run the below code in Terminal for Google Application Credentials :

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/mac/Desktop/Bigquery-Key.json"
```

Then set the below configuration in Jupyter Notebook :

```
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
# Imports the Google Cloud Client Library 
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Instantiates a Client for Bigquery Service
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
```

Now, i wanted to write a Python script(.py file) which will do both the tasks instead of using Terminal.

How can it be done ? Kindly advise ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the environment within a Python script. The environment is stored in the dictionary `os.environ`:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/mac/Desktop/Bigquery-Key.json"
```